# How to solve probability when sample space is infinite?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I came up with a random problem yesterday:

> Suppose that in a random trial, each point $(x,y)$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$ is assigned a value of $0$ with 50% chance and a value of $1$ with 50% chance. What is a chance that there is a 'continuous path' that joins the point (0,0) and the point (1,1), such that along the path every single point has the same assigned value?

My intuition sort of says that the probability should be zero, but I don't really have a good reason why. For one thing, any particular path from (0,0) to (1,1) should have a 0% chance of occurring, but there are also an infinite number of possible paths from the point (0,0) to (1,1). In my head, the probability should depend on whether the "zero" was smaller than the "infinity"

$$P \simeq \text{num paths} * P(\text{chance a path happens})$$

To evaluate the number of total paths, I sort of imagined constructing paths with straight lines. To construct an arbitrary path between (0,0) and (1,1), I would pick some number of intermediate points inbetween the two corners, and specify their $x$ coordinate and $y$ coordinate. Something like:

$$\text{num paths} \simeq \aleph_1^2 + \aleph_1^4 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + \aleph_1^{\aleph_0} \simeq \aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$$

(First term is like I have to pick 2 real numbers for a single intermediate point, second term is if I pick 4 real numbers for two intermediate points, and so on)

To evaluate the chance that any particular path happens, it's sort of like saying that for every point along the line, it must be assigned the same value. Hence, its sort of like:

$$P(\text{chance a path happens}) \simeq \frac{1}{2}^{\aleph_1}$$

So combining the two, we have (very unrigorously):

$$P \simeq \aleph_1^{\aleph_0} * \frac{1}{2}^{\aleph_1}$$

This seems not only super unrigorous, but I'm not even sure if you can even do this kind of thing. My friend's words keep echoing in my head, "something something probability only means something when the sample space is actually defined properly something something" 
Is the problem (as I have posed it) even meaningful in any sense? And does my poor attempt at a solution have any grain of meaningfulness in it?

Comment: I'm afraid there are already problems with defining the setup rigorously. We'd like to see this as a set-valued random variable (for the set of points in $[0,1]^2$ that are assigned "1"). For this we must find a suitable measure space in $\mathcal P([0,1]^2)$. And then hope that the desired connectivity property is measurable ...

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but there is a paper called [Axiom of choice and chromatic number of the plane](http://shelah.logic.at/files/E33.pdf) by Shelah and Soifer that deals with a slightly related problem. The chromatic number of the plane involves partitioning the plane into 2 or more sets (similar to what you are doing), and this paper shows that things can behave badly in this situation. For example, the answer to the problem investigated by the paper has a different answer depending on whether we accept the axiom of choice.

Comment: It seems that the probability is zero. For any path you have uncountable points and all of them must have a 1... Anyway seems hard to tell rigorously.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to make this question more rigorous, but another thing to consider is that, in order for there to be a continuous path of "1"s from (0,0) to (1,1), there cannot be any continuous path of "0"s from anywhere on the right/bottom edge to the top/left edge.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PercolationTheory.html    This is close to percolation theory (in particular continuum percolation). Quite a lot of references available,  intense area of research.  Good luck.

Comment: Suppose probability of there being a "0" path (excluding endpoints) is p > 0. Then, from an _obvious_ symmetry, the probability of a "1" path from (0,1) to (1, 1/n) within the 1 x 1/n rectangle should also be p. The same for paths from (1/n,1) to (1, 2/n), etc. Thus, p < (1-p)^n for arbitrary n.