# Infinite 'hex': is a win always achievable?

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory

In the game [hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)), at least one player always wins because they can form a chain of hexagons across the board. This led me to wonder, what happens if we generalise to infinitely many points?

Specifically, if every point in a unit square (including boundaries) is coloured red or blue, does there necessarily exist a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]\times [0,1]$ such that $f(x)$ is either

a) Always red$\space\space$ and $f(0)=(0,a), f(1)=(1,b)$ for some a,b

b) Always blue and $f(0)=(a,0), f(1)=(b,1)$ for some a,b

Furthermore, if there exists a function such that (a) is true, then does that necessarily mean there does not exist a function such that (b) is true?

(In the example, red wins with the path shown an blue loses)

[image: square filled with red and blue dots, with a green wavy line from left to right]

My intuition tells me that this is true, but I have no idea how to begin proving it. My best idea was to colour the regions to the left and right of the square red. Then anything connected to this red region is marked green. If the other side is connected to this then we are done. Otherwise, take the points along the boundary of this green region. They must be blue otherwise there exists a point closer to the region that is blue (by definition of the green region). Hence this boundary reaches all the way down to the bottom and we are done. But I'm not sure if this green region is well-defined or anything and have no idea how to show that it is.

(Also, I've got no idea what tag(s) to put on this, sorry)

Comment: Interesting question! I can at least help with the second half of the question, whether both can be true at once: the Jordan Curve Theorem shows that that is impossible. (The paths of your two functions must intersect by the JCT, and their intersection point cannot simultaneously be red and blue.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803419/how-to-solve-probability-when-sample-space-is-infinite

similar-ish question

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No.  In fact, it is possible to color the entire unit square red and blue so that there is *no* nonconstant continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$ whose image is entirely one color.  The key observation is that the image of any such nonconstant function is a closed subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, and there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ such closed subsets.  You can then construct a coloring by transfinite induction so that each such set has both a red point and a blue point.

In detail, let $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ be an enumeration of all the closed subsets of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.  We define sequences $(r_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ and $(b_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ by induction.  Having defined $r_\beta$ and $b_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, define $r_\alpha$ and $b_\alpha$ to be two distinct points of $X_\alpha$ which are not equal to $r_\beta$ or $b_\beta$ for any $\beta<\alpha$.  This is possible since we have chosen fewer than $\mathfrak{c}$ points so far, and $X_\alpha$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

We thus obtain two disjoint sets $R=\{r_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ and $B=\{b_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ which each intersect every $X_\alpha$.  Color all the points in $R$ red, and all the points in $B$ blue, and all the points that are in neither $R$ nor $B$ however you want.  Then neither the red points nor the blue points contain any $X_\alpha$, and thus neither contains the image of a nonconstant continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

---

However, it is true that *at most* one of your conditions (a) and (b) are true.  See [this answer to an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1937554/86856) for a proof. (The proof there assumes the endpoints of the paths are the corners of the square, but a similar argument works in general.  Or, you can apply a homeomorphism of the square that sends the endpoints of the paths to the corners.)

Comment: I wonder whether the axiom of choice can be avoided here...

Comment: Just a question, how come the number of nonconstant functions in a closed subset of [0,1] x [0,1] is c?

Comment: I assume you mean to ask why the number of closed subsets of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is $\mathfrak{c}$?  The space $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ has a countable basis, and so every open set is determined by a subset of that countable basis which it is the union of.  So there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ open sets, so there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ closed sets.

Comment: As a perhaps stronger version of what @Wojowu asked, can $f$ be made measurable?

Comment: It may just be me, but this seems to ignore the hexagon-style movement over the square-grid movement that makes the standard game Always result in a winner.

Answer (score 6):

Color $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ red if $x=0$ or $y=1/2\cdot\sin(1/x)$. Color everything else blue. There are no paths of either color connecting its respective edges.

[image]

Note that the red path does not "reach" the line $x=0$. See also this post and the counterexample in the answers: ["Intermediate Value Theorem" for curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280823/intermediate-value-theorem-for-curves)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, thinking about it more has gotten me this answer:

Consider the colouring:

$(x,0)$ is always blue

For each natural number n,

$(\frac{1}{n},y)$ is blue iff $\frac{1}{n}\leq y$, and everything else is red.

Comment: @EricWofsey 0,t is red for t>0

Comment: Oh, I misread.  But blue still wins: try $f(t)=(t/2,t)$.

Comment: Okay. I'll switch back to my original function that I thought of then; hopefully that one works

Comment: @EricWofsey Does that work?

Comment: Looks good to me!